# Spring boot @RequestBody add property before saving into the database

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm using `springboot` and `mongodb`. I've a `Customer` model as below:

```
package com.example.customerapi.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Configuration

@Document(collection = "customer")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6748432793461621268L;

    @JsonProperty("customer_id")
    private String customerId;

    @Field("type")
    private String type;
    
    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @JsonProperty("middle_name")
    private String middleName;

    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;

    @JsonProperty("phone")
    private String phone;

    @JsonProperty("note")
    private String note;
    
    @JsonProperty("date_of_birth")
    private String dateOfBirth;

    @JsonProperty("sex")
    private String sex;
    
    @JsonProperty("contact_address")
    private Address address;
    
    @CreatedDate
    @JsonProperty("create_timestamp")
    private LocalDate createdDate;
    
    @LastModifiedDate
    @JsonProperty("modified_timestamp")
    private LocalDate modifiedDate;
    
}
```

Here, `type` is not a part of `RequestBody`. Please find below `CustomerController`.

```
package com.example.customerapi.resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.customerapi.repository.CustomerRepository;
import com.example.model.Customer;
import com.example.customerapi.dto.CustomerResponse;

@RestController
public class CustomerController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    
    @PostMapping(value="/addCustomer", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity<CustomerResponse> saveCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        
        try {
            customer.setType("test_type"); //this is not working
            return new ResponseEntity<CustomerResponse>(new CustomerResponse(customerRepository.save(customer)), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            return new ResponseEntity<CustomerResponse>(new CustomerResponse("Error saving customer"), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

But before saving customer into database I would like to set `type` in `Customer` to a sample string.

**How do I set object properties that are not a part of `RequestBody`?**

Comment: Why do you say it is not working? Do you get any exceptions? You do not, but the data is not persisted? As a side note, you can remove `@Configuration` from `Customer` class.

Comment: @Joāo Dias you're right. There's no exception but data is not getting stored as intended. I cannot set type on customer before saving it in database.

Comment: My bet is that the issue is with the MongoDB Document definition in your class, but I am not that experienced with Mongo. Nevertheless, I guess that you don't need `@Field("type")`.

Answer (score 0):

Use @transient above

```
@Transient
private String type;
```

The field will be ignored